# How to search for numbers in filename/data in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have 10 files in a folder. All with similar pattern with text and number:

```
ABCDEF20141010_12345.txt
ABCDEF20141010_23456.txt
ABCDEF20141010_34567.txt
...
```

I need to process these files in a loop.

```
for filename in `ls -1 | egrep "ABCDEF[0-9]+\_[0-9]+.txt"`
do
  <code>
done
```

Above `egrep` code, is not going inside the loop. Can you please help me in modifying this search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `ls` and `grep`. It's working with shell-only functionalities:

```
for filename in ABCDEF[0-9]*_[0-9]*.txt
do
  echo $filename
  #do whatever
done
```